# Read and Uptade txt.file in Asp .Net Core using RichTextEditor

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rich-text-editor

I want to read a static txt file, edit, and save it again as a txt file in my asp .net Core MVC web application.

I was wondering if I can achieve this by using one of the rich text editors available (e.g. TinyMCE, CKEditor, or Quill).

Below is the code I currently have.

**Controller**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
           
            return View(new Script());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Script script)
        {
            return View(script);
        }
 private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(tr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
```

**Class**

```
 public class Script
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
   
        [AllowHtml]
        public string code { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
@model Models.Script

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<body>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Scripts", FormMethod.Post))
    {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.code)<br/>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.code,"",new { @class = "error" })
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <span>@Html.Raw(Model.code)</span>
    }
</body>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/7wyujejhpvi3ixga3ss1q5gqwvocaiozzy83w2gvwcd004s4/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'a11ychecker advcode casechange formatpainter linkchecker autolink lists checklist media mediaembed pageembed permanentpen powerpaste table advtable tinycomments tinymcespellchecker',
            toolbar: 'a11ycheck addcomment showcomments casechange checklist code formatpainter pageembed permanentpen table',
            toolbar_mode: 'floating',
            tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
            tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Have you got any code. Have you tried anything? We cant assist you if we don't know what you have tried.

Comment: I have updated it thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo about how to read and upload the txt file:

Firstly,create a txt file in your local computer.

View:

```
@model Models.Script

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<body>
    <input type="file" value="import"/>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.code)<br/>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.code,"",new { @class = "error" })
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <span>@Html.Raw(Model.code)</span>
    }
</body>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/7wyujejhpvi3ixga3ss1q5gqwvocaiozzy83w2gvwcd004s4/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'a11ychecker advcode casechange formatpainter linkchecker autolink lists checklist media mediaembed pageembed permanentpen powerpaste table advtable tinycomments tinymcespellchecker',
            toolbar: 'a11ycheck addcomment showcomments casechange checklist code formatpainter pageembed permanentpen table',
            toolbar_mode: 'floating',
            tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
            tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
        });
        $("input").change(function () {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function () {
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(fr.result);
            }
            fr.readAsText(this.files[0]); 
        });         
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Script()
        {
            id = 1,
            code = "<h1>hello</h1>"
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Script script)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\xxx\\Sample.txt");  
        //Write a line of text
        sw.WriteLine(script.code);
        //Close the file
        sw.Close();
        return View(script);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]